# php function to find position of one of the multibyte chars

Tags: php, multibyte

Is there a standard function in php which can return position of first occurrence of one of the multibyte symbols?

In whole the task is as follows. I have multibyte string and position in this string and I need to find first occurrence of one of the symbols (delimiters). I written the following function, but it unfortunately works very slow.

```
$delimiters = array( 
    "\r", "\n", "\t", ".", ";", "!", "?"
);

function get_cit_end($str, $end) {
    global $delimiters;
    if( $end >= mb_strlen($str) )
        return mb_strlen($str) - 1;
    $c = mb_substr($str, $end, 1);
    while( $end < mb_strlen($str) ) {
        if( in_array($c, $delimiters) )
            break;
        $end++;
        $c = mb_substr($str, $end, 1);
    }
    return $end;
}
```

Comment: why don't you use http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php ?

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`mb_strpos()`](http://php.net/mb_strpos), like this:

```
function get_cit_end($str, $delimeters) {
    $index = -1;
    foreach( $delimiters as $d) {
        if( ($i = mb_strpos( $str, $d)) !== false) {
            $index = $i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if( $index == -1) return mb_strlen( $str) - 1;
    return $index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you enable `mbstring` function overloading, you could use the normal `strpos()` function with multibyte strings:

The following mbstring-variables should be set via php.ini or vhost-configuration; they wont work per directory (i.e. via .htaccess).

- mbstring.language = Neutral
- mbstring.internal_encoding = UTF-8
- mbstring.func_overload = 7

See also: http://php.net/mbstring